# Выделяется ли запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми слово "прямо", в значении "прямо(,) тут"? Предложение, которое интересует: "Прямо(,) на уроке математики?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Частицы обычно знаками препинания не выделяются.